# How to combine stored procedure and select query result?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to combine the results of `xp_cmdshell` with a select query.
I have tried union & read about creating a temp table, but as my result will be having only 1 column. To be more precise i need a smaller query to combine the results of `xp_cmdshell` with select query as am trying to use it in union based sql injection

For example:

```
Select name from employee
union
exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

I know this wont work but somewhat similar would be great :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a temp table and do insert into #temp EXEC.. or use OPENROESET. Refer this
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10812/select-columns-from-exec-procedurename-is-this-possible.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should know what this stored procedure returns and what outputs. Then when you know the table schema this procedure returns you may use the following syntax:

```
DECLARE @procedureOutput nvarchar(max)
SET @procedureOutput=Exec xp_cmdshell 'dir'
SELECT name FROM employee union @procedureOutput
```

If you need convert two different data types, `CAST` and `CONVERT` commands are for you.

Comment: Thanks!! Still wont work... throwing error at Exec... trying to make it work :)