# Insert data into table using select & execute procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to insert data into table using both select statement and executing procedures.

That is... suppose a table 'TEMP' has 4 columns A,B,C,D. A & B column values will be coming from SELECT statement and C, D column values will be come by executing any stored procedures.

I have tried following but didn't facing error.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP
SELECT R1.A, R1.B, R2.C, R2.D FROM 
(SELECT A , B FROM SOME_TABLE) AS R1
CROSS JOIN EXEC [dbo].[SOME_PROCEDURE] @SOME_VARIABLE1 ) AS R2
```

ERROR IS:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'
```

Comment: @Aquillo Sry. that's R2.

Comment: We have a similar question here. Try this  :


[How to combine stored procedure and select query result][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503067/how-to-combine-stored-procedure-and-select-query-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Stored Procedure in JOIN . First store resultset of stored procedure in a temp table and then use this temp table in JOIN.

```
-- First create the table to which we want to push the SP result
CREATE TABLE #TempTableName(..........)

-- Insert result from the SP to temp table
INSERT INTO #TempTableName
EXEC [dbo].[SOME_PROCEDURE] @SOME_VARIABLE1
```

Then do the joining

```
INSERT INTO TEMP
SELECT R1.A, R1.B, R2.C, R2.D FROM 
(SELECT A , B FROM SOME_TABLE) AS R1
CROSS JOIN #TempTableName AS R2
```

Answer (score 1):

check this...

```
declare @var int

    exec EXEC [dbo].[SOME_PROCEDURE] @SOME_VARIABLE1,@output=@var


    INSERT INTO TEMP
    SELECT R1.A, R1.B, R2.C, R2.D FROM 
    (SELECT A , B FROM SOME_TABLE) AS R1
    CROSS JOIN @var) AS R2
```

Comment: YOU mean i should return output variable?